# FuelPHP V 1.7.2 Fatal error: Class 'Input' not found

Tags: php, php-5.3, fuelphp

Hey I'm a starter to FuelPHP framework, I'm using version 1.7.2 , I already made my first application, Which is working perfectly in local Virtual host (windows/Wamp) , thou it didn't work well on linux server when I uploaded (I tried 2 different hosts, the same problem exists) 
this is all what I get and I don't really know where to start looking :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Input' not found in /var/www/vhosts/carex.benseno.com.tr/httpdocs/fuel/core/classes/uri.php on line 326

Fatal error: Class 'Input' not found in /var/www/vhosts/carex.benseno.com.tr/httpdocs/fuel/core/classes/error.php on line 273
```

note: I extend the Class Uri, and add it to the autoloader, and I don't use any namespacing.
if anyone has an Idea that would be very appreciated

edit: Autoloader:

```
Autoloader::add_classes(array(
    // Add classes you want to override here
    'Uri' => APPPATH.'classes/extension/uri.php',
));
```

Note: Removing the class from autolaoding doesn't change anything, Errors are the same, I don't think it's related to the error.

Comment: And it works under windows? Where do you add the extension to the autoloader?

Comment: @mark.sagikazar I edited the question, There isn't any problem under windows, I setup a virtual host ofcourse, using Wamp Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, After a long time of debugging, strange enough, setting `'locale' => false,`
in `config.php` file solved the problem.
which as the documentation explains :

> Used for setlocale() required on some php installations, set to false
>   to prevent it from being set. The syntax setting for this can differ
>   per OS, Ubuntu for example requires a .utf8 (the encoding) suffix.
>   http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/configuration.html